# How to reset the file.stream in flask / werkzeug?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

It seems to me, that you cannot access `file.stream.read()` after the file has been written with `file.save('path',filename')` and vice versa.

Example code (derived from the file uploading pattern):

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from werkzeug import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            print '##########################'
            print os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            print file.stream.read() # <- gives no output
            print '##########################'
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 24):

You should be able to [`seek`](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) back to the start of the stream. (See Werkzeug's docs on [`werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage)).  When you try to read the file a second time you *start* reading from the end of the file.

```
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
file.stream.seek(0) # Go back to the start of the file
print file.stream.read() # <- should work now.
```

Comment: Thank! But is is not working for me.I still get no output in bash. :(

Comment: You just saved 10 hours of my life

Comment: This is a good answer. Although one would have to know the root cause of the issue already to find this answer :)